# Connection refused from local machine to bitcoind

Tags: rpc, bitcoind

I have bitcoin node installed and configured on Ubuntu 18.04 with the purpose of using RPC/JSON API calls and make a bitcoin service.

My application is built in Laravel 5.8, I use laravel-bitcoinrpc package to connect to the node. If the application is on the same server as the node is, I can connect and make RPC calls, but when I try to connect to node from my local machine (laptop) I receive connection refused.

I have allowed my local IP address.

```
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8332                       ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       89.165.xxx.xx - My IP address
8332                       ALLOW       89.165.xxx.xx - - My IP address
8332/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
18332                      ALLOW       89.165.xxx.xx - - My IP address
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8332 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8332/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

This is my bitcoin.conf

```
prune=600
maxconnection=20
maxuploadtarget=20
daemon=1
server=1
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=password
rpcport=18332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=<my-local-ip->
rpcbind=<my-local-ip->
keypool=10000
rpctimeout=30
```

rpcallowip should allow me to connect to the node from the remote user but I still get connection refused.

I have also allowed the ports on my router.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `rpcallowip=0.0.0.0`.

Comment: This will block localhost to connect also...not working